# Programs that reproduces itself

Tags: java, quine

Is it possible to make a Java program that prints its source code to a new file, and compiles it, and runs the compiled program?

Comment: That would get you into an infinite loop :).

Comment: Since Java programs can spawn other processes, that seems to be a straightforward combination of a quine and spawning the compiler, then the newly compiled result.

Comment: +1 cause I cant stop thinking about why one would like to do such a thing.

Comment: @TRA no, it suddenly came up from my mind

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.
A trivial implementation would be: have the source code contain itself in a string, save the string to a file and fill its own string with the same string (otherwise, the initial string would be of infinite size, due to the recursive manner of this implementation), compile the file, and run the compiled file (which will, in turn, do the very same).

Non-trivial implementations are significantly harder.

Comment: "have the source code contain itself in a string" How? Since the string would be part of the source code, this would lead to an infinite string.

Comment: I edited my post to clarify this. The source code should contain itself in a string, including everythign except the content of this string, which is to be filled at runtime after the source-code was deployed to a text file (before it is being compiled).

Comment: Have a look at my answer and follow the link to rosetta code. There's an example!

Answer (score 23):

#### Update:

Okay, might as well make it autorun. Enjoy the madness. Run at your own risk.

---

Yes it's possible, because I actually wrote it up. <strike>It doesn't do the RUN part (that's just too crazy, because as others have mentioned, it will cause an infinite loop),</strike> but here it is: `Quine.java`

```
import java.io.*;
public class Quine {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      char q = 34;
      String out = "Quine$";
      String text = (
         "import java.io.*; " +
         "public class [OUT] { " +
           "public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception { " +
             "char q = 34; String out = `[OUT]$`; String text = `[TEXT]`; " +
             "PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(out + `.java`); " +
             "pw.format(text, 34, out, text); " +
             "pw.close(); Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime(); " +
             "runtime.exec(`javac ` + out + `.java`).waitFor(); " +
             "runtime.exec(`java ` + out); " +
           "} " +
         "}"
      ).replace("`", "%1$c").replace("[OUT]", "%2$s").replace("[TEXT]", "%3$s");
      PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(out + ".java");
      pw.format(text, 34, out, text);
      pw.close();
      Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
      runtime.exec("javac " + out + ".java").waitFor();
      runtime.exec("java " + out);
   }
}
```

So here's how to get the craziness to start:

- `javac Quine.java` to compile
- `java Quine` to run it

  - It will produce, compile and run `Quine$`
- I've made sure `Quine.java` is as readable as possible, so the *major* difference from `Quine$.java` are formatting and the 3x `replace`. The *minor* difference is that `Quine$.java` has `out` set to `Quine$$`.
- `Quine$` will produce, compile and run `Quine$$`
- `Quine$$` will produce, compile and run `Quine$$$`
- `Quine$$$` will produce, compile and run `Quine$$$$`
- ...

Do note that this doesn't do any reverse-engineering or cheat by reading the `.java` source code, etc. `Quine` is a quine-generator because it produces a different code differently formatted, but `Quine$` is pretty much a true self-contained quine: it does reproduce itself, it just relabels it `Quine$$` (which reproduces itself and relabels to `Quine$$$` etc).

So technically there's no infinite loop: it will eventually come to a halt when the file system can't handle another `$`. **I was able to manually stop the madness by forcefully deleting all `Quine$*` files, but run at your own risk!!!**

Comment: I know that it has been a while since this had been posted, but maybe you could make it switch between 2 different file names, then delete the previous

Answer (score 6):

Sure it works - Have a look at [rosetta code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Main_Page) and navigate to Quine, which is *a self-referential program that can, without any external access, output its own source*.

There's one example for a quine in Java.

Answer (score 5):

> Programs that reproduces itself or Self Replicating Programs are known as [Quine Programs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine_%28computing%29)

Sample Program in **Java** which reproduces itself.

```
public class QuineProgram {

     public static void main(String[] args){
      String f = "public class QuineProgram { "
        + "public static void main(String[] args)"
        + "{ String f =%c%s%1$c;"
        + " System.out.printf(f,34,f);}} ";
      System.out.printf(f, 34, f);
     }

}
```

Output:

```
public class QuineProgram { public static void main(String[] args){ String f ="public class QuineProgram { public static void main(String[] args){ String f =%c%s%1$c; System.out.printf(f,34,f);}} "; System.out.printf(f,34,f);}}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the Java Compiler API (JSR-199) for this. Below, code from the JSR-199 that compiles code from a String (slightly modified to make it compile). The code actually compiles source code from the `String` into a byte array (i.e. it doesn't write to disk), loads it and then executes it via reflection:

- [`MemoryFileManager.java`](http://pastebin.com/CMVvhZT5): A file manager for compiling strings to byte arrays.
- [`ByteArrayClassLoader.java`](http://pastebin.com/XjeLikkD): A class loader which loads classes from byte arrays.
- [`CompileFromString.java`](http://pastebin.com/66wHPjhK): The class that wrap everything together.

That could be a starting point (credits to Peter Van der Ahé, the original author).

BTW, you need of course a JDK to use this API.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly what you want, but I think [BeanShell](http://www.beanshell.org/) is something you can use.
BeanShell is an interpreter. You can run uncompiled Java-code (So you give it a String with code and he runs it).

Of course if you really want to do what you wrote, the machine where the program is running needs a JDK to compile your program.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I dont think it will work in Java. Wouldn't that involve overwriting a running class file.

Suppose your program is in Quine.java compiled to Quine.class.

Now Quine.class will attempt to write its output to Quine.java (so far so good), and compile it to Quine.class. This is gonna be a problem as Quine.class is already running

Comment: Erm ... he didn't require the new cloned program to be launched in the same VM (from the same classpath).

Comment: but it will be, as each copy of the program has to be identical, so you cannot change filenames every time

Comment: Identical programs need not behave identically. They can use random number generators. They can interact with the host system, e.g. use the first unclaimed file name.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - don't forget to use a JDK instead of a JRE:

1. Bundle the app's source code files with the app.  The app would copy the source files to a new set of source code files, compile the new source files, bundle the new source code with the new class files into a new app, and then spawn the new app.

   or
2. Bundle a decompiler with the app.  The app would run the decompiler on its own class files to generate new source code files, compile the new source files, bundle the decompiler with the new class files into a new app, and then spawn the new app.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Java Quine using preview text block feature (-source 13 --enable-preview) where output is formatted the same as input:

```
package org.sample.quine;

public class QuineProgram
{
  public static void main(String...args)
  {
    String f ="""
package org.sample.quine;

public class QuineProgram
{
  public static void main(String...args)
  {
    String f =""%c%c%s%1$c"";
    System.out.printf(f, 34, 10, f);
  }
}
""";
    System.out.printf(f, 34, 10, f);
  }
}
```

Output:

```
package org.sample.quine;

public class QuineProgram
{
  public static void main(String...args)
  {
    String f ="""
package org.sample.quine;

public class QuineProgram
{
  public static void main(String...args)
  {
    String f =""%c%c%s%1$c"";
    System.out.printf(f, 34, 10, f);
  }
}
""";
    System.out.printf(f, 34, 10, f);
  }
}
```

Heavily Commented Version:

```
package org.sample.quine;

public class Quine
{
  public static void main(String...args)
  {
    // Inside text block use "" followed by token or token followed by "" so that we don't prematurely close text block
    String f ="""
package org.sample.quine;

public class Quine
{
  public static void main(String...args)
  {
    // Inside text block use "" followed by token or token followed by "" so that we don't prematurely close text block
    String f =""%c%c%s%1$c"";
    /* Tokens in template text block, each prefixed with percent symbol
     * 1(c)   third quote (34) of open block delimiter
     * 2(c)   new line    (10) of open block delimiter
     * 3(s)   String f         text block that goes between two text block delimiters
     * 4(1$c) first quote (34) of close block delimiter,
     *        1$ means first argument after template argument
     *        2$ would be second argument after template argument
     */
     // Arguments - 1 template (String f); 2 "; 3 newline; 4 template again without replacing tokens
     System.out.printf(f, 34, 10, f);
  }
}
""";
    /* Tokens in template text block, each prefixed with percent symbol
     * 1(c)   third quote (34) of open block delimiter
     * 2(c)   new line    (10) of open block delimiter
     * 3(s)   String f         text block that goes between two text block delimiters
     * 4(1$c) first quote (34) of close block delimiter,
     *        1$ means first argument after template argument
     *        2$ would be second argument after template argument
     */
    // Arguments - 1 template (String f); 2 "; 3 newline; 4 template again without replacing tokens
    System.out.printf(f, 34, 10, f);
  }
}
```