# Java self print program without file io

Tags: java, file

Can anyone tell me how to write a java program that print itself without using file IO. I googled a lot, but I can't find the exact answer. [I found some useful tips here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2617792/programs-that-reproduces-itself) . Is there any way to write self print program without using file IO ?

Comment: What do u mean by "self print"?

Comment: what do you mean by "file IO"?  Be specific.

Comment: The question seems absolutely clear to me !

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[Here](http://www.nyx.net/~gthompso/self_java.txt) you can find many implementations, the first by Bertram Felgenhauer follows:

```
class S{public static void main(String[]a){String s="class S{public static void main(String[]a){String s=;char c=34;System.out.println(s.substring(0,52)+c+s+c+s.substring(52));}}";char c=34;System.out.println(s.substring(0,52)+c+s+c+s.substring(52));}}
```

By the way, this is known as a quine, a program whose output is *itself*.

Comment: @frhack I have taken it from the link. It is not my original creation :p

Comment: Yes I know. Still a good answer !